# I get an error message when trying to create a Cmake project in visual studio 2022

Tags: python, installation, cmake, cmake-modules

I chose setup with python embedded system in Visual Studio 2022
and I get cmake for windows from individual setup
I did get cmake from choosing Python embedded system setup but for Linux

I have tried various ways such as installing CMake manually

this is the error message

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/Light/source/repos/CMakeProject3/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-kebu5e
    
    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe -v cmTC_e0e9c && [1/2] "C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"  /nologo   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -Zi /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_e0e9c.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_e0e9c.dir\ /FS -c C:\Users\Light\source\repos\CMakeProject3\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-kebu5e\testCCompiler.c
    [2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_e0e9c.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- "C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_e0e9c.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_e0e9c.exe /implib:cmTC_e0e9c.lib /pdb:cmTC_e0e9c.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    FAILED: cmTC_e0e9c.exe 
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_e0e9c.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- "C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_e0e9c.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_e0e9c.exe /implib:cmTC_e0e9c.lib /pdb:cmTC_e0e9c.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_e0e9c.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_e0e9c.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specified
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.        C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake    67
```

I tried all day to fix this, but it still didn't work, and I just think the error is just in the CMake module